# foreachBatch not getting executed in Spark stream write

Tags: python, apache-spark, stream, databricks

I seems like the run_command function is not run in the below code. What is wrong?

```
df.writeStream \
    .foreachBatch(run_command) \
    .format("delta") \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/delta/events/_checkpoints/") \
    .partitionBy("machineid") \
    .toTable("mytimeseriesdata")

n = 100
count = 0

def run_command(batchDF, epoch_id):
  global count
  print("something")
  count += 1
  if count % n == 0:
    spark.sql("OPTIMIZE mytimeseriesdata ZORDER BY (timestamp)")
    print("Optimizing " + count)
```

Comment: If you are expecting to see prints on console then streaming app doesn't allow print or df.show() operation so better check from backend whether `spark.sql()` is being executed.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Can you give some more pointers on where I can see that? We're using Azure databricks.

Comment: For unsupported operations please refer to this - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#unsupported-operations. To verify whether `run_command` function is being called  for every row, use the console sink for debugging as mentioned here - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#output-sinks

Comment: I now changed the .format("") to "console" but I cannot see any additional output. In many examples the last command is .start where I use .toTable. Could that affect?

Comment: `.toTable()` is an option of `format('delta')`. You need `start` in both the cases. It is mandatory option to start the stream.

Comment: Ok, I’ll try to add .start. But the above code is actually working and data is written to the table without .start. It’s only foreachBatch that is not triggered.